# How To Implement Custom keyboard with UISearchBar?

Tags: iphone, xcode, keyboard, uisearchbar

In My application i develope a custom keyboard in one of local language.Now this keyboard works fine with UITextField and UITextView.For both these i implement the Custom keyboard like this.

```
textField.inputView = Customkeyboard;
textView.inputView = Customkeyboard;
```

But when i implement its for UISearchBar

```
searchBar.inputView = Customkeyboard;
```

its gives me Following Error.

> error: object cannot be set - either readonly property or no setter found

i also set its property and Synthesis,but unable to solve this problem.Can any one help me to solve this problem.Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to class documentation of [UIResponder](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIResponder)

> The value of this property is nil. Responder objects that require a custom view to gather input from the user should redeclare this property as readwrite and use it to manage their custom input view. When the receiver subsequently becomes the first responder, the responder infrastructure presents the specified input view automatically. Similarly, when the view resigns its first responder status, the responder infrastructure automatically dismisses the specified view.

Okay, create a class inherited from UISearchBar like below .h and .m files. In your .h file ad the folowing lines

> @interface SearchBar : UISearchBar
>   @property (readwrite, retain) UIView *inputView;
>   @end

In your current controller where you are using this, replace UISearchBar with SearchBar.

> searchBar.inputView = Customkeyboard; // Where searchBar is an object of SearchBar and not UISearchBar

Comment: Yes, you are correct when you say its not yours, therefore you need to add the above lines. You need to add the above lines to present this as per documentation

Comment: No you have not customized the searchbar. You need to subclass this searchbar. Like I have done above and then do what you do

Comment: Cool idea but i don't know where is mistake.

Comment: Its not only the main class that you need to change. You need to create another different class(.h and .m) which inherits from UISearchBar. Then you need to use an object of that search bar

Comment: i create the classes as u mention this time no error but my searchbar display defualt keyboard instead of custom keyboard.

Comment: plz check my updated question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843523/customkeyboard-implemention-with-uisearchbar

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to set it for the searchbar, both `UITextField` and `UISearchBar` inherit from UIResponder which has the property UIView as readonly, however UITextField overwrites the property and makes it `readAndWrite`, but searchBar does not.

You can of course create a subclass of UISearchBar and re-declare the property, and it *might* work.

Comment: Thanx for quick response if u give the email address then i want to share code with,bcz this problem struck me a lot.thanx

Comment: There is not much to it, you just have to subclass it and declare the re-declare the property as @property (readwrite, retain) UIView *inputView;, like S.P is pointing out on his answer.

Comment: plz check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843523/customkeyboard-implemention-with-uisearchbar