# Customkeyboard Implemention with UISearchBar?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, keyboard, uisearchbar

I try to implement customkeyboard with UISearchBar .first of all my mainclass.h where i use UISearchBar is look like this

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@class PashtoKeyboard;
@class SearchBar;
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController<UISearchBarDelegate > {
  IBOutlet SearchBar *searchBar;
  PashtoKeyboard            *pashtoKeyboard;
}
@property(nonatomic,retain)     PashtoKeyboard  *pashtoKeyboard;
@property (nonatomic,retain) SearchBar *searchBar;
@end
```

Now my mainclass.m

```
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import "PashtoKeyboard.h"
#import "SearchBar.h"
@implementation MainViewController
@synthesize pashtoKeyboard,searchBar;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
//Create Pashto Keyboard
 PashtoKeyboard *pashtoKey = [[PashtoKeyboard alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 460.0-216.0, 320.0, 216.0)];
[pashtoKey loadView];
//[self.view addSubview:hebKey];
[pashtoKey addTarget:self action:@selector(pashtoKeyboard_clicked:) forControlEvents:1001];
[pashtoKey addTarget:self action:@selector(pashtoKeyboardBackspace_clicked:) forControlEvents:1002];
[pashtoKey addTarget:self action:@selector(pashtoKeyboardEnter_clicked:) forControlEvents:1003];
[self setPashtoKeyboard:pashtoKey];
//[hebKey setHidden:YES];
[pashtoKey release];
    searchBar.inputView = pashtoKey;
    searchBar.delegate=self;
    searchBar.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
   }

#pragma mark Pashto Keyboard Methods
 - (void) pashtoKeyboard_clicked:(id)sender{    
   [searchBar setText:[pashtoKeyboard keyboardText]];
   }
 - (void) pashtoKeyboardBackspace_clicked:(id)sender{   
   [searchBar setText:[pashtoKeyboard keyboardText]];
   }
 - (void) pashtoKeyboardEnter_clicked:(id)sender{   
   [searchBar setText:[pashtoKeyboard keyboardText]];
   }
```

In SearchBar.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface SearchBar : UISearchBar {
}
@property (readwrite, retain) UIView *inputView;
@end
```

in SearchBar.m

```
#import "SearchBar.h"
@implementation SearchBar
@synthesize inputView;
- (void)dealloc {
[super dealloc];
}
@end
```

And then finally i have PashtoKeyboard.h and PashtoKeyboard.m where i create my custom keyboard,due to large coding i not show these classes code here i tested  its  with textveiw and textfield.
But it not works  with UISearchBar .can some one guide me how to do this.thanx

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this at all?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `inputView` of the `UITextField` that the `UISearchBar` is using in order to get the user input.  You can do this by searching through the subviews of the search bar and finding the text field.  Add this to the `viewDidLoad` method of your `mainclass`:

```
for (UIView *view in searchBar.subviews) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass: [UITextField class]]) {
        UITextField *textField = (UITextField *)view;
        textField.inputView = // Your custom keyboard (PashtoKeyboard)
        break;
    }
}
```